# Struggle with function strtok() in C

Tags: c, string, strtok

I need to use strtok function to analyze every word in some strings.
I wrote a code like:

```
char *token;
token=strtok(string,symbol);
while(token!=NULL){
   functionX(token); //this is a function that anlayze the token
   token=strtok(NULL,symbol);
}
```

but the "functionX" only receive first words of the strings and null pointer then.
If I put

```
printf("%s",token);
```

instead of functionX it print every piece of the string.
How can I solve this?

This is what I called "functionX":

```
void match(char *token, char *code){
FILE *rules;
char *tmp_token;
char stream[15];
int found;
rules=fopen("rules.vk","r");
found=0;
while((fgets(stream,sizeof(stream),rules))>0){
    tmp_token=strtok(stream,";");
    if((strcmp(tmp_token,token))==0){
        strcpy(code,strtok(NULL,";"));
        found=1;
    }
}
if(found==0) strcpy(code,token);
```

}

Comment: can you show "functionX" function code?

Comment: @MohdShahril Yup. 
It's a function that associate every token to a translation according to some rules written in a file.
That's:
pastebin.com/rBKi1Bx0

Comment: Please post a minimal version of `functionX` which exhibits the fault *in the question*. It's no use adding a commented link - even more so when it's a dead link.

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: You have not checked the return value from `fopen`. It's essential to do so. And you didn't close the file afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the difficulties in using `strtok`. It has internal state in the routine, which keeps track of the position in the string that was passed in originally (i.e. the first `strtok(string, symbol);` call).

This information gets messed up when you call `strtok` inside the `functionX` as it changes the internal pointer. Then when you return you're using this erroneous state.

What you need to use is the `strtok_r` routine, which keeps a private copy of this pointer which you have to pass into the call to `strtok_r`.

As an example for the original routine, you could change it to:

```
char *token;
char *save;
token=strtok_r(string,symbol, &save);
while(token!=NULL){
   functionX(token); //this is a function that anlayze the token
   token=strtok_r(NULL,symbol, &save);
}
```

and the inner routine could be changed to:

```
void match(char *token, char *code){
    FILE *rules;
    char *tmp_token;
    char *save;
    char stream[15];
    int found;
    rules=fopen("rules.vk","r");
    found=0;
    while((fgets(stream,sizeof(stream),rules))>0){
        tmp_token=strtok_r(stream,";", &save);
        if((strcmp(tmp_token,token))==0){
            strcpy(code,strtok_r(NULL,";", &save));
            found=1;
        }
    }
    if(found==0) strcpy(code,token);
}
```